# How do you populate data on the new Individual Object?

Tags: contact, leads, gdpr, individual

As part of the gearing up to GDPR, Salesforce is releasing the new Individual object that is associated with Contacts and Leads. There are instructions in the release notes that point to turning the object on and adding the field onto the page layouts of Contacts and Leads but... How can you create an individual? How do you make sure it is associated with the right Individual (contact or lead)? How do I add data?

I could create a new tab and add that to the app and then add data that way. etc but why wouldn't this all be automatic when it is turned on. Why isn't there an automatic Individual for every Lead and Contact?

Comment: I believe the question is too broad and also brings in too many levels including the business domain. You give the technical answer yourself (Tabs). Insert on `Indivdual` in Apex work with API >=42.0. 
There are no automatisms (yet?) to identify the 'right' individual.

Comment: Interesting question I am now looking into myself. It is a shame Salesforce have not allowed us to bulk create Individuals for all Contacts. I am writing some execute anonymous Apex to generate these, but will then have to create a trigger/workflow to update the new individual records.

Comment: I created a Process and a Flow to do it. It'll happen on any update to the person objects. Main issue is one of data allocation: this doubles the space taken up by each person so I'm trying to be clever about how we comply with GDPR: If they are not an EU resident then we don't do it.

Comment: @SeanGorman - Individual doesn't count toward your storage usage, good news!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Create a new flow. The logic of a flow: a new Individual record created/edited and associated with the Contact/Lead record that started the process. You will need one process/flow per object (Lead/Contact/Account).

The flow contains 2 steps: record creation and update of the original record with the ID of the newly created record.

[image]

Step 1: Creating a new Individual record. You probably want to pass certain field values from the record that started the process to populate a newly created record:

[image]

In order to do so, you need to create a sObject variable (of the same type) that the record that starts the process and map the fields. Make sure the 'Input/Output Type' of the variable is set to 'Input and Output'.

[image]

The last thing you need to do in the first step is to assign the ID of a newly created record to a flow variable. It could be private as we are not going to send it outside the flow.

Step 2: you need to update the record that started the process with the newly created record by entering its ID into the lookup field.

[image]

Step 3: Set start element and activate the flow. Now the flow will be available in the process builder. Hint: If you had Process builder open on another tab, you want to close and restart the builder, so the list of available flows is updated

Next, we want to send the sObject that started the process into the flow. There is no need to send individual values of the fields, just entire object.

[image]

After the activation, the entire process looks like this:

- The process starts the evaluation of a record when it is created/updated.
- If the criteria matched, the process sends the contact to the flow.
- Flow creates a new record and associates it back to the record that started the process.

Known issues and limitations:

1. Make sure you are not hitting DML limits. The flow creates 1 and updates 1 record. The batch size should not be more than 100 records (200 DML Limit / 2 actions).
2. Create a strict rule in the process, so the infinite loop is not created when a flow updated back the record that started the process. (i.e.: Contact changed and Individual field is blank)
3. Make sure the same record is not passed to the flow more than once as it will lock the process.

Comment: Yes - that's exactly what I did in February. I'm wondering if Salesforce will implement this as an automation before GDPR/ePR

Answer (score 0):

Create a trigger on the object, this has worked perfectly for me and is immediate:

```
trigger ContactInsertTrigger_IndividualCreation on Contact (after insert) { 

    //Map of Id to Individual - this will allow us to store the contact Id against the new Individual record, 
    //and then to update the contacts with the Individual Id once they've been created 

    Map<Id, Individual> createTheseIndividuals = new Map<Id, Individual>();

    List<Contact> theContacts = new List<Contact>(); 

        //FOR loop to run through Contact records in trigger.new 

    for(Contact c : trigger.new){ 
        createTheseIndividuals.put(c.Id, new Individual(FirstName = c.FirstName, LastName = c.LastName, Salutation = c.Salutation));
    } 

    //Insert the values (individuals) in the createTheseIndividuals map 

    insert createTheseIndividuals.values(); 

    //Another FOR loop to update the contact with the Individual Id 

    for(Contact c : trigger.new){ 

        Contact theContact = new Contact(Id=c.Id); 

        theContact.IndividualId = createTheseIndividuals.get(c.Id).Id; 

        theContacts.add(theContact); 

    } 

    //DML to update the contacts in theContacts 

    update theContacts; 

}
```